# Hibernate3 grails3 plugin

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-3.0

I want to use  hibernate-3 plugin for grails3 app, where can I find it? The one which goes with `create-app` command. `compile"org.grails.plugins:hibernate"` is using hiberante4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my understanding that there are no plans on supporting Hibernate 3 going forward, but of course the community could create a plugin if there's a demand.

Hibernate 5.0.2 has been released and they're working on Hibernate 6 - Hibernate 3 is very old and it's time to move on :)

Comment: Is this information present in the Grails Documentation ?